# Is wpf touch screen specific?

Tags: wpf, windows, touchscreen

I have developed a application for a client who uses windows 7 home premium x64 with touchscreen. when i deploy application after some time the application crashed.when i tried to debug in client system the error is **Recursive call to the automation peer api** after some research in internet i found out this article [Click On The Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/6c4465e2-207c-4277-a67f-e0f55eff0110) 
When i debug in client system it shows error in different pages. is their any other way to fix this problem. Kindly Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how i have found out a solution. when i stop the tablet input service from the windows services the application runs fine. so i have integrated code in windows loaded to stop the service and in windows closed i have integrated the code to start the service. i know it is not the correct solution but for the time being till microsoft release a patch of .net framework.